# Android ImageView in right of TextView with layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have TextView with android `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, where is the user nickname and in the right of TextView.I want to add an ImageView,where I set the status of the user (red or green) but the status image is still in left (`layout_toEndOf="@+id/username"` is set).

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/username"
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:textColor="#921090"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username"/>
```

Comment: `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/status"` add this Textview section

Comment: Use a Linear Layout instead. Your problem will solved

Comment: Try removing `layout_alignParentTop` from `ImageView`

Comment: put image of screen and also how you want to make it. so We can imagine what you want to make?

Comment: did you try `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableEnd` with textview? it will show small imageview with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#921090"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://screencloud.net/v/DPBm    android:layout_centerInParent="true" its not from there! I need to use RelativeLayout because the layout its more complex and it is a <ScrollView>

Comment: What is this?? @FedotSerghei

Comment: what exactly you want ? add rough picture  of it.

Comment: Ok got you. Please check my answer now. @FedotSerghei

Answer (score 0):

have tried with `android:weightSum` so it will be supported in all device with diffrenet resolution.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#921090"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/cal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#921090"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/username"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope you find this useful,......